# How to calculate the inverse of $f(t) = \frac{(k/2)(\sin(t) + t) - t}{2π (k/2 - 1)}$?

Tags: inverse-function, trigonometric-series, lagrange-inversion

This function arises from a specific problem in optical engineering.  I am modeling a light source whose amplitude is being modulated sinusoidally.  I have derived this function which describes the cumulative quantity of light emitted over time:

$$f(t) = \frac{\left(\frac{k}{2}\right)(\sin(t) + t) - t}{2π\left(\frac{k}{2} - 1\right)}$$

where $k$ is a constant modulation depth, and $0 ≤ k ≤ 1$.

**EDIT:** This simplifies further to

$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2π}\left[\frac{k}{k-2}t + \sin(t)\right]$$

but I think that this does not affect my questions.

This function is also normalized, so that one period of oscillation delivers one measure of light, independent of $k$.

Here's a graph of $f(t)$ at various modulation depths over the interval $[0, 4π]$ to make the normalization more apparent.

[image: graph of f(t) at various modulation depths]

Now, to model photon flux as a time series, I will need $f^{-1}(t)$.  I need a general solution for all $t$.

**EDIT:** I am OK with a series approximation.  See immediately below, I discuss $\arcsin$, which does not have an analytic solution.

I have searched for possible ways to derive my answer from the known $\arcsin$ series expansion.  I think this may not be possible.  Does a shortcut exist?

Alternately, I think I might have to apply the [Lagrange Inversion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem).  This theorem is new to me, but I suppose it is how the series for the inverse trig functions were derived in the first place.  The Wikipedia entry jumps straight into the deep end of the pool, and I am unsure how to start.  Are there simpler explanations of the Lagrange Inversion Theorem available, and/or examples of other functions being inverted that I might study?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Many times, even if we are able to show that a function is invertible, we are not able to provide an expression in terms of the usual functions in calculus. It is just the way things are, and the series representation of the inverse does not solve this problem, it just gives a representation of the inverse that is usable in the numerical approximation of the inverse.

Comment: Yes, I am OK with a series approximation.  It seems pretty obvious that my inverse function would have something resembling an arcsin term as a part of it, and arcsin does not have an analytic solution.

Comment: This is essentially [Kepler's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation). It's fairly easy to invert using Newton's method, if you have a reasonable starting approximation.

Comment: @PM2Ring: thanks for that tip!  

I just found a blog post (https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2021/04/01/efficient-kepler-equation) and a manuscript released just this year (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.15829.pdf) which discuss efficient solutions to Kepler's equation.  I'm reading the manuscript now to see whether it is relevant -- but Figure 1 says to me that I'm on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the equation as
$$f(t)=\frac{(2-k) t-k \sin (t)}{2 \pi  (2-k)}$$ using the trivial bounds of the sine function, we have
$$\frac{(2-k) t-k }{2 \pi  (2-k)} \leq f(t) \leq \frac{(2-k) t+k }{2 \pi  (2-k)}$$ which gives as bounds
$$2\pi\, f(t)-\frac k{2-k} \leq t \leq 2\pi\, f(t)+\frac k{2-k}$$ One iteration of Newton method would give
$$t_1=2 \pi  f(t)-\frac{k \sin (2 \pi  f(t))}{k \cos (2 \pi  f(t))-(2-k)}$$

Trying for $f=1.75$ and $k=0.75$ would give, as an *estimate*, $t=\frac{7 \pi }{2}-\frac{3}{5}=10.3956$ while the solution given by Newton method is $t=10.4750$.

Answer (score 0):

You function can be reduced to  $$ f(t) = w \sin(t) + v t $$ this function as shown in [wolfran alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=inverse%20f%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%20%3D%20w%20sin%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%20%2B%20vt) does no have explicit  inverse (or at least their inverse is a hell to derivate). And by Langrange inversion thoerem we get (If I didn't make astupid mistakes)

$$ t = t_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(f(t) - f(t_0))^n}{(n + 1)!} v^{-n} $$
where $t_0$ is the offset